# Referencing script variables into input fields

Tags: pine-script

I have a strategy sending signals to my bot.
I wish to use the notation as in picture
to send the bot specific take profit and stop loss values, dynamically taken from my script. What should I do to reference my variables inside the input fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Input field expects a `const string` so you cannot pass a variable there.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

s = "Test "
i  = 10
t = s + str.tostring(i)
s_test = input.string(s)    // Fine
//s_test_2 = input.string(t)  / /Error

plot(close)
```

[image]

That field is probably there so you can enter specific commands for your bot (enter, exit etc.)

If you want to use variables in your order message, you should use the `alert()` function.

Comment: I'm using some guy's strategies (which code is private unfortunately) which actually have those fields, where you can enter those placeholders between hashtags and they are replaced correctly with values. I don't know how he does.
I know I can do this entirely inside the script, but I wish to share my strategy with private code and let users customize their bot signal. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I solved this with str.replace(). Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I used `str.replace()`.
Basically you get the input variable (the whole text message) and pass it thru `str.replace()` n times as many variables you have to replace, each time using the previous obtained new string.
In my case, if I wish to replace #LongSL# and #longTP#, I will write as following:

```
new_enterLong_msg = str.replace(original_enterLong_msg, "#LongTP#", str.tostring(LongTP), 0)
new2_enterLong_msg = str.replace(new_enterLong_msg, "#LongSL#", str.tostring(LongSL), 0)
```